# Make contents of flex item scroll instead of making container taller

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, semantic-ui

I have a dialog box:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
        .content {
            display: flex !important;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
                    
        .ui.modal > .content > .scroll {
            flex: 1;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui overlay fullscreen modal">
  <div class="header">
    Dialog box
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui warning message">
      <div class="header">
        Be careful
      </div>
      This is a warning message
    </div>
    <div class="scroll ui segment">This box should scroll when the contents are too long.</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Part of the dialog box</div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui approve button">Save</div>
    <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, if the contents of the large box (the one that says that it should scroll) are too long, then it will make the entire dialog box scroll. I don't want this, I want the contents of the box to scroll without making the entire window scroll, like this:

[image: scroll dialog box]

How can I do that?

Comment: Switch from this `.scroll { flex: 1; }` to `.scroll { flex: 1 1 1px; overflow: auto; }`. https://jsfiddle.net/akzsn1Lx/

Comment: This worked correctly, could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Just needed to verify that this solution worked for you. It's actually a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `max-height` and `overflow-y: auto;` to that element to not let it get any higher than a certain height and make it scroll only if necessary due to its contents:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ui.modal>.content>.scroll {
  flex: 1;
}
.scroll.ui.segment {
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui overlay fullscreen modal">
  <div class="header">
    Dialog box
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui warning message">
      <div class="header">
        Be careful
      </div>
      This is a warning message
    </div>
    <div class="scroll ui segment">This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when
      the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long.
      This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when
      the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long.
      This box should scroll when the contents are too long. This box should scroll when the contents are too long.</div>
    <div class="ui segment">Part of the dialog box</div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui approve button">Save</div>
    <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```