# CSS Flex Overflow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow

I want to make a website with a list using bootstrap + css's flexbox, where the item list should have a height up to the screen's bottom not overflowing it.

I was able to get a working solution like this:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper .content {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 224px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="topbar"></div>
        <div class="main">
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

With the help from this link:
[Prevent flex item from exceeding parent height and make scroll bar work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487743/prevent-flex-item-from-exceeding-parent-height-and-make-scroll-bar-work)

As you can see the scroll bar's bottom arrow is at the end of the screen.  (Expected behaviour)

However, when I try to expand my main div into 2 more columns (using bootstrap + flex):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper .content {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 224px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 1px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.details {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="topbar"></div>
        <div class="main">
          <div class="header col-lg-4">
            <div class="item">item</div>
            <div class="item">item</div>
            <div class="item">item</div>
            <div class="item">item</div>
            <div class="item">item</div>
            <div class="item">item</div>
            <div class="item">item</div>
          </div>
          <div class="details col-lg-8"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the item list overflow below the bottom of the screen.  (see the bottom arrow of the scrollbar is missing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `min-height: 0;` to .main element

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link you attached with the explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of fixed lengths in your code, including:

```
.side {
  width: 224px;
}

.topbar {
  height: 100px;
}
```

These hard limits make the solution to overflow problems relatively simple, since the easiest way to trigger a scrollbar is to create an overflow condition, which is best accomplished with a fixed length.

In this case, the `.topbar { height: 100px }` is the key to the scrollbar on the sibling element.

(Note that you need to disable `flex-shrink` on these lengths for the values to always be respected.)

Here's a revised version of your code, with various adjustments for greater performance and efficiency.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.side {
  /* width: 224px; */ /* will not be respected without adding `flex-shrink: 0` */
  flex: 0 0 224px;    /* new; flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex: 1;  /* consume remaining space */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .content-wrapper .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topbar {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  /* height: 100px; */
  background-color: aqua;
}

.main {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px); /* new; sets overflow condition */
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.details {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 200px;  /* not a flex item, so no need to disable flex-shrink */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="topbar"></div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="header col-lg-4">
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
          <div class="item">item</div>
        </div>
        <div class="details col-lg-8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5p8dok47/2/)

Comment: Hi Michael_B,  Thanks for solving it so quickly.  I wonder if there's another way where I don't have to use height: calc(100vh - 100px) but use flex instead? (i.e. consume the rest of the space)

Comment: Try adding `height: 100vh` to `.content`, and `height: 1px; flex-grow: 1` to `main`. https://jsfiddle.net/vLu3rz5t/