# Flexbox: how to not overstretch a nested flexbox by an oversized child element (along cross axis)

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, stretch

I have a nested set of flexboxes, mostly passing on identical size downwards. In the innermost flexbox, there is an image. If that image is too long along any axis, I want scrollbars on the innermost (purple) box.

[image]

I learned already how to prevent overshooting along the main axis ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489012), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145461)). Basically

```
flex: auto;
width: 0;
overflow: auto;
```

But I have no Idea, how to limit along the sizing cross-axis.
*(Note: cross-axis is vertical here. Green and blue box have a horizontal main axis as their (default) flex-direction is 'row'.)*

https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/BayNPJq?editors=1100

Comment: add `min-height: 0;` to `.one, .two`

Comment: Thank you. There are actually 3 different solutions ().

Comment: Btw: I found closing right away as "duplicate" a bit harsh: The linked question (and single answer) certainly has good pointers (focussing on ”main axis”, not necessarily cross axis) but does not provide a specific answer for my scenario (a mix of main and cross axes in a nested scenario with a flex-directional change within). I think, as such it does deserve an own answer. (Or else we could just close any scenario-specific-question here and point to some W3C document, some webpack documentation, some...)

Comment: *but does not provide a specific answer for my scenario* --> a duplicate is never meant to provide a *sepcific* answer. A duplicate is a generic/canonical question that deals with the same issue and it's up to you to find the needed answer/code to your question based on the knowledge provided by the duplicate. You are having an issue with min-height/min-width constraint and the duplicate explain that issue which is the missing piece of puzzle

Comment: I respectfully disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `height: 100%;` to `.one, .two` so your flex elements will only get the available space in height

---

*(Addition by Questioner.)*

### Interesting, there appear to be 3 solutions to this:

1) to `.one` add (also to `.two` won't hurt, and probably a good idea recalling IE-crossbrowser-issues)

```
min-height: 0;
```

2) to both `.one, .two` add:

```
height: 100%;
```

3) to `.one` add (also to `.two` won't hurt. Won't truncate borders on children btw (which is a good sign), still all properly visible on all edges)

```
overflow: hidden;
```

*Imho (1) is the "cleanest" solution... (as it fixes the root cause, probably also the safest bet against cross-browser-issues)*

Comment: Well done, Thierry! I added in (below the dash) all three solution I found.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm sure it will help many people