# Why does my <ul> element always overflow in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a  element in my interface with quite a lot of elements. As soon as the list extends over a entire screen, a scrollbar should appear in the list. The  element is set to take up the remaining height space in the Right column via flex-grow. Without the list elements, the  element fills the remaining height perfectly. however, as soon as there are too many elements for one screen in the  element, the entire  tag and thus screen overflows.

The `<div id=content">` element overflows in height over the space of the `<body>` element althoug I set the bodies `max-height` property to `100vh` which seems off to me.

Here is a small example with my code:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/john-dizzle/pen/BaQLawM?editors=1100)

**How can I adjust the code to display the  element with many elements showing scrollbars on the y-axis?**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSV Parser Tool</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS & JS-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- PLOTLY JS -->
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <a class="btn btn-danger mr-xl-3 mr-l-3" href="{{ url_for('reset') }}" role="button">Reset</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="content" class="flex-grow-1 container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-xl-6 h-100">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
          <h2>File Picker</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xl-6 h-100">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
          <h2>This is my overflowing list view</h2>

          <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <ul class="overflow-scroll">
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Element</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does your question about not able to scroll with all the items? I think you should just add a specific height for the overflow-scroll container.

Comment: vh's are like percentages. 100vh is the full height. 1vh is about 5px

Comment: @MarLMazo Thats right, I want the items to be scrollable.Therfore I want the `<ul>` elemement to take the remaining height of the right column instead of setting it to a specific height using fixed pixel or percent measures.

Comment: @Shanie Thanks for the notice, I will correct that. But it seems that this doesn´t change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144972/flexbox-avoid-child-with-longer-height-than-parent-column-direction) by adding a `min-height=0` property to the flex-grow parent and child elements.

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class=""> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Element</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it